# My jframe is coming up blank with no colors

Tags: java, swing

Here is the code hopefully someone can help. According to everything i learn this should work as a blue Jframe but its not. I am a little bit of a noob thoe so be gentle. Also ignore the stuff in spam unless that has to do with it

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame{

    private long beforeTime, afterTime, diff = 0;



    public HelloWorld () {
        //spam();
        setTitle("Computer Quest");
        setSize(640,480);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void spam() {
        for (int i = 1;  i<= 10; i++) {
        beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
        log("Welcome to computer quest");
        afterTime =System.nanoTime();
        diff = afterTime - beforeTime;
        log("Time taken"+ diff);
        }
    }

public static void main (String[] args) {
new HelloWorld();
}
    private void log(String s) {
        System.out.println(s); 


    }
}
```

Comment: getContentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

Comment: Try `getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);`

Comment: @mrKorbel getContentPane needs `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

with

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

The reason why your solution doesn't work is because it's not the `JFrame`'s natural background that's visible, but the content pane's This is why you have to apply the color to the content pane instead of the `JFrame`.